# Using Cartopy on Google Colab: crashes every time

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, cartopy

Simply running the block of code below crashes the runtime on my Colab Notebook every time. It specifically happens when `ax.coastlines()` is called through Cartopy. Does anybody know the explanation/fix for this issue?

```
!apt-get -qq install python-cartopy python3-cartopy
import cartopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Draw coastlines of the Earth
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
```

Comment: Can you include any error messages / crash output if there is any

Answer (score 1):

The runtime logs show the problem:

```
python3: geos_ts_c.cpp:3991: int GEOSCoordSeq_getSize_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, const geos::geom::CoordinateSequence*, unsigned int*): Assertion `0 != cs' failed.
```

Searching online points to this GitHub issue:

[cartopy possibly kills the kernel when using ipython/jupyter notebook](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/738#issuecomment-197138438)

I'd start by following the recommendations there. But, this seems a library issue in cartopy and its deps.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted [my answer on the github thread](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/738#issuecomment-1459815575), but it's probably useful here too:

I have just discovered a not so ugly work-around for the issue which effects the COASTLINE feature in the pip installation of cartopy, e.g. the `ax.coastlines()`.
The trick I found to work was to use the LAND feature instead, minimum reproducable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, edgecolor='black', facecolor="none", linewidth=1)
```

I found that this solved the issue when running a notebook on Colab.
(I also had to manually set the zorder to make sure it was above my data layer)